# How to model SQL Server database view in Visual Studio using EF Core?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ef-core-2.0, database-view

I created a view in SQL Server. I want to model that view in Visual Studio using EF Core as the ORM with a database-first approach. I appreciate if anyone can tell me about the solution.

Answer (score 0):

For EF Core 2.1, create an entity class with the same name as your view and properties to match your view fields. then add to the database context like:

```
public DbQuery<MyView> MyView {get; set;}
```

It can then be queried from the context as you would for a DbSet, e.g:

```
  context.MyView.First();
```

Before 2.1, create the entity class and add it to your context as a DbSet:

```
public DbSet<MyView> MyView { get; set; }
```

Then use a string db query to select from the view:

```
context.MyView.FromSql("select * from MyView"));
```